# "Localhost" and "127.0.0.1" come back with server error but Apache "it works!" page displays on another ip

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2, localhost

I am so new to all this, so please be gentle with me. I am running Ubuntu server on a Virtualbox on a Windows 8 machine so I can install Omeka and build content prior to finding a hosted solution. 
I installed Ubuntu and tried to configure the LAMP but when I would access "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" from my web browser there was nothing there.  I ran "iconfig" and tried the IP provided there and it worked! So I installed Omeka and went through that configuration and now when I go to the IP that did work I can the message that "index.php" is missing. 
So how can I resolve this?  Obviously I need to:
1) Get 127.0.0.1 working as the local host (and it is defined as such in /etc/hosts) OR
2) get Omeka to recognize the other IP as "localhost"
As I said, please be gentle.  I am trying to learn...
Many thanks in advance,
Meredith

Comment: Are you trying to connect to `localhost` from a browser in Windows or from a browser within Ubuntu?

Comment: I have tried both from Windows (IE, Firefox, and Chrome) and also from Firefox within Ubuntu. None of them work.

Answer (score 0):

I've never dealt with Omeka, so I can't help with that.

## How to set up VirtualBox so that the LAMP server on Ubuntu's address will be `127.0.0.1` on Windows

Paraphrasing [the VirtualBox manual's section on port forwarding](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward):

- If you want the LAMP server to work only on your actual machine:

  1. Open a Windows command prompt.
  2. Run the following, replacing `VM name` with the virtual machine's name and replacing **both** `80`s with the LAMP server's port number:

     ```
     VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natpf1 "lamp,tcp,127.0.0.1,80,,80"
     ```
- If you want the LAMP server to work for everyone on your LAN and possibly the whole Internet:

  1. Open a Windows command prompt.
  2. Run the following, replacing `VM name` with the virtual machine's name and replacing **both** `80`s with the LAMP server's port number:

     ```
     VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natpf1 "lamp,tcp,,80,,80"
     ```

Now you'll be able to access the LAMP server on Windows using the address `127.0.0.1`.

## How to set up Windows so that `localhost` is the same thing as `127.0.0.1`

1. Log in to Windows as an administrator.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the `Run` dialog.
3. Run `notepad %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.
4. Add the following line to the file:

   ```
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   ```
5. Save the file.

Now you'll be able to access the LAMP server on Windows using the address `localhost`.

Comment: Thank you for this.  When I run the command I get the error "VBoxManage is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

Comment: I just checked and I have it set to "Bridged Networking", a requirement for Omeka installs on VirtualBox.  Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's a problem. Unfortunately, my answer above only works with NAT instead of bridged mode. With bridged mode, you have to use the IP address for the virtual machine to access it. As for running `VBoxManage`, it's probably not in your path. `VBoxManage.exe` will be located in the VirtualBox folder (something like `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox`). You can `cd` to that directory and then run the commands from there.